# Load html with javascript inside a webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load an html file into a webview but the webview remains blank. Can someone please help me to achieve this ?

here is my html

```
<script src="http://france.meteofrance.com/portlet/plugins/meteo/VignetteMeteoVille3.javascript?idLieu=431200" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

this is on create method

//oncreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.rss_feed);

     webcontent = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewHistoire);

     webcontent.setWebViewClient(new NewsClient());

     webcontent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     webcontent.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);

     webcontent.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

     webcontent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");


}
```

//back key

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webcontent.canGoBack()) {

        webcontent.goBack();    

        return true;

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

private class NewsClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please refer http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Grishu i have updated the post

Comment: the html file is in assets folder

Comment: did you tried with any phonegap android samples.. in that you will have the idea to call javascript file using html.. from android webview.

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> to your manifest.xml file??

Answer (score 1):

Is your html file code written in `<html>` tag ? if not then please write it as below:

> ```
> <html> 
>   <head>
>  <script language="JavaScript"  src="http://france.meteofrance.com/portlet/plugins/meteo/VignetteMeteoVille3.javascript?idLieu=431200" charset="UTF-8">
>  </script>
>  </head>
>   </html>
> ```

And try to load it in webview.

Comment: yes it is in the body tag it is working fine when loaded in pc browser